# VLC Media Player New Window Problem

Tags: vlc, window

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and the 3.0.8 Vetinari VLC Media Player. When I have a video already playing and I double-click on another video, another VLC window opens. I find this totally unnecessary. Is there a way to prevent this? I want VLC to use just one window when I open another video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VLC (v 3.0.8) Tools , Preferences, tick All, type instance, click playlist, tick allow only one running instance.

Comment: I have this problem in linux but can't solve it this way. And I tried `killall vlc` and `pkill -9 vlc` that works! but sometimes not working!

Comment: just guessing, but try them sudo

Comment: Not depends on `sudo`. I can't find an exact way to solve this problem.

Comment: "show settings: All" radio button on left bottom corner

Comment: also I can use killall -9 vlc